# data.frame colmn mean at n-th interval of rows

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I tried to find similar questions here but thought that it might be helpful to just create new question.

I have relatively large dataset (daily weather data for several hundreds stations)
I did some sliding window average calculation and I got the intermediate output like this.

data frame of `10481441 row` by `11 column` but my row names are consist of series of numbers with identifiable prefix.

For example,

```
X1.1
X1.2
X1.3
...
X1.11659
X2.1
X2.2
X2.3
...
X2.11659
X3.1
...
X899.11659
```

Then what I want to do is get mean values of `11 columns` by same prefix of row numbers

For example:
for `11 columns` `mean(X1.1,X2.1,X3.1,...X899.1) (X1.2,X2.2,X3.2,...X899.2)` and thus expect to have a output table as `899` set of `11659 row` by `11 column`

I got some help here to have jumping average at n-th row when I have `as.Date` row names but wasn't able to modify the desired format to run.

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new column with the desired category, and use that in `aggregate`.  Here is an example:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:12)
rownames(d) <- paste0('X', rep(1:4, 3), '.', rep(1:3, 4))
d
##       x
## X1.1  1
## X2.2  2
## X3.3  3
## X4.1  4
## X1.2  5
## X2.3  6
## X3.1  7
## X4.2  8
## X1.3  9
## X2.1 10
## X3.2 11
## X4.3 12
```

This looks something like your data.  Now add the categories as a new column.  If you split each name on `.`, you want the second entry returned:

```
d$category <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(d), '[.]'), '[', i=2)
d
##       x category
## X1.1  1        1
## X2.2  2        2
## X3.3  3        3
## X4.1  4        1
## X1.2  5        2
## X2.3  6        3
## X3.1  7        1
## X4.2  8        2
## X1.3  9        3
## X2.1 10        1
## X3.2 11        2
## X4.3 12        3
```

And aggregate based on this new column.  `.` here means "all other columns" so you will get means of everything other than the new column:

```
aggregate(.~category, data=d, FUN=mean)
##   category   x
## 1        1 5.5
## 2        2 6.5
## 3        3 7.5
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. to add this task, if I want to average columns within X at n-th interval rows. For example, mean(X1.1,X1.nth,X1.2n-th,X1.3n-th...)(X2.1,X2.n-th,X2.2n-th...)... could you also help me on this..?